# Pass variable as condition for if-statement or filter

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

I'm curious to know how I might achieve something like the following in R.

I hope this psodu-code illustrates the concept.

```
g <- 10
condition <- "g > 9"
if(condition) print("This works")
```

Specifically, does anyone know if it is possible to do something like this with the dplyr filter function? (Again, psudo-code):

```
df <- data.frame(one = 1:5, two = 6:10, three = 11:15)
condition <- "two == 7 | one == 1"
filter(df, condition)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to set your string as an `expression`.

```
g <- 10
condition <- expression(g > 9)
if (eval(condition)) print("This works")
# [1] "This works"
```

This is what the `parse` function in Tim's solution is doing, and that is a more generalised solution than this one in most cases.

Comment: Kevin and Tim, thank you both for your response. I'm marking Kevin's as correct, because it requires one less command. Both are very clean though.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `eval` with `parse`:

```
g <- 10
exp <- "g > 9"
eval(parse(text=exp))
[1] TRUE
```

This approach should scale to more complex expressions, including those making function calls.